# How to add "Run as CLI Application" to Zend studio 9 Run/Debug toolbar?

Tags: zend-studio

By default configuration in a new workspace I have "Run as Web Application" in the run/Debug toolbar menu.

How should I configure the workspace|project to add the "Run as CLI Application" to the menu items?

Comment: in case someone else has the same question, I created a new project from the same source code then selected the CLI in the launch settings and the run as php cli application is back in it's place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another way to do it is to enable "Enable CLI Debug" at php debug configurations in zend studio preferences

Answer (score 0):

just to provide a bit of reference here on a mac os x 10.6, zendstudio 9

**for a project**

1. right click on the project
2. select properties
3. select php debug
4. enable project specific settings
5. select from php executable PHP 5.3.15 (CLI) or whatever is applicable
6. check the Enable CLI Debug checkbox

**for zend studio**

1. got to the menu Zend Studio
2. select Preferences
3. open the PHP section
4. select the Debug submenu
5. select from php executable PHP 5.3.15 (CLI) or whatever is applicable
6. check the Enable CLI Debug checkbox

you can then right click on a php file and run as PHP CLI Application